# Replacing of variables but not subscripts

Tags: replacement

It's an extremely brief question. I want to replace all variables in an expression to another ones, say $x \rightarrow y$. But the command

```
x + Subscript[a, x] /. x -> y
```

replaces also the subscript. How can I do replacements while leaving the `Subscript` object unchanged?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to do replacements with a pattern that shouldn't be changed, I like to use multiple replacement rules (as in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166629/45431)):

```
ReplaceAll[
    x + Subscript[a, x],
    {
        s_Subscript :> s, (* pattern to avoid *)
        x -> y
    }
]
```

> y + Subscript[a, x]

Comment: Thanks. It's bit more general solution, thus it suits me better then the answer above.

Comment: It may be worth quoting the documentation to explain why this works: "The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part or on any of its subparts."

Answer (score 1):

It's an extremely brief answer:

```
x + Subscript[a, x] /. Subscript[a_, x] :> Subscript[a, z] /. {x -> y, z -> x}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify briefly whether the command 
 x + Subscript[a, x] /.   Subscript[a, x] ->  Subscript[a, z] /. {x -> y, z -> x}
is wrong. That is, can we replace function-like notation a_ with a, and delayed reduce :> with a simple reduce symbol -> ?

Comment: It works but only for subsripts of `a`. So, it does not work for `Subscript[b_, x]`, for example.

Comment: Anyway, your answer is witty. I thought, that there should be something more straightforward.